# Passing in a TIME parameter to a Time aware WMS Provider using Mapsui

Tags: c#, .net, wms, mapsui

I'm trying to add additional params when creating the WmsProivder using Mapsui. I read in the documentation that at the moment Mapsui doesn't automatically fetch the ServiceDescription, so you have to add the additional parameters to the URL. However when I try that I always get a "Service tag not found" error.

```
 private static async Task<WmsProvider> CreateWmsProviderAsync()
 {
     var wmsUrl = "https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/eventdriven/services/radar/radar_base_reflectivity_time/ImageServer/WMSServer?SERVICE=WMS&TIME=";
     wmsUrl = wmsUrl + DateTime.Now.AddHours(-12).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ");
     var provider = await WmsProvider.CreateAsync(wmsUrl);
     provider.ContinueOnError = true;
     provider.TimeOut = 20000;   
     provider.CRS = "EPSG:3857";
     provider.AddLayer("0");
     provider.SetImageFormat(provider.OutputFormats[1]);
     return provider;
 }
```

What is the proper way to achieve this?

The link to the WMS GetCapabilities document is [here](https://mapservices.weather.noaa.gov/eventdriven/services/radar/radar_base_reflectivity_time/ImageServer/WMSServer?request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WmsProvider has an ExtraParams field, which is a dictionary, the key/value pairs will be added as extra parameters to the request.

The url you specify is the root of the WMS service which should not be changed to add parameters.

Comment: This only seems to work for future hours, but not hours in the past... the WMS definitely supports past hours, as can be seen [here](https://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmapservices.weather.noaa.gov%2Feventdriven%2Frest%2Fservices%2Fradar%2Fradar_base_reflectivity_time%2FImageServer&source=sd)

Comment: The ExtraParams is just a way to add a parameter. It is up to you what that parameter looks like. It is hard for me to imagine that there is a limitation in that mechanism. I think you need to alter the format of the parameter. Perhaps you need to url-encode the parameters first.

Comment: you're right, seems to be the DateTime string format, should be ISO String and uri encoded, strangely though ```DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")``` should be ISO Format... will have to look into this.

Comment: I figured this out. Is ExtraParams capable of being updated on an interval. For example I wan't to update the time param every so often, does a simple override of the extraparam suffice or must this be done another way? @pauldendulk

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77261216/85325